# How to view all symfony commands executing in real-time?

Tags: php, symfony, command

I use command to run my own service which executes commands with different parameters with help of Symfony/Process. I need to know exactly what commands are executing at this moment. Is there any command to track or something else to help?

Comment: `ps -eaf | grep "bin/console"`

Comment: thanks that helped!